# Pass array as parameter to JAX-RS resource

Tags: arrays, jax-rs, parameter-passing

I have many parameters to pass to the server using JAX-RS.

Is there a way to pass or AarryList with the URL?

Comment: Is it possible that from a client side we send parameters as an xml  as PUT method and on the server side we can receive it using JAXBElement ( wrapping as an object )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a few options here.

### Option 1: A query parameter with multiple values

You *can* supply multiple simple values for a single query parameter. For example, your query string might look like:

`PUT /path/to/my/resource?param1=value1&param1=value2&param1=value3`

Here the request parameter `param1` has three values, and the container will give you access to all three values as an array (See [Query string structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure)).

### Option 2: Supply complex data in the `PUT` body

If you need to submit complex data in a `PUT` request, this is typically done by supplying that content in the request body. Of course, this payload can be xml (and bound via JAXB).

---

Remember the point of the URI is to identify a resource ([RFC 3986, 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)), and if this array of values is data that is needed to identify a resource then the URI is a good place for this. If on the other hand this array of data forms part of the new representation that is being submitted in this `PUT` request, then it belongs in the request body.

Having said that, unless you really do just need an array of simple values, I'd recommend choosing the Option 2. I can't think of a good reason to use URL-encoded XML in the URL, but I'd be interested to hear more about exactly what this data is.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the Query parameters and corresponding values as a Map,

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void test(@Context UriInfo ui) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = ui.getQueryParameters();
    String name = map.getFirst("name");
    String age = map.getFirst("age");
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(age);
}
```