# REST passing Parameters with Java

Tags: java, rest, parameters

I've built a REST webservice with some webmethods.
But I don't get it to work passing parameters to these methods.

I.E.

```
@GET
@Path("hello")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String hello(String firstName, String lastName){

    return "Hello " + firstname + " " + lastname
}
```

How would I invoke that method and how to pass the parameters firstname and lastname?
I tried something like this:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

Client client = Client.create(config);

WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

ClientResponse response = service.path("hello")
.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).put(ClientResponse.class);
```

But where do I add the parameters?

Thank you for your help,
best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) tutorial should be of help. To include parameters you will need to use the `@PathParam` command as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514470/how-to-create-a-restful-web-service-with-input-parameters) previous SO Post.

Comment: thank you helped me alot. But what if my method wants an array of Strings?

Comment: @Chris: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484209/pass-array-as-a-parameter-in-restful-webservice

Comment: Thank you very much. That link was also helpful to the context of your last link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718575/how-can-i-grab-all-query-parameters-in-jersey-jaxrs

Comment: There i have explain more method for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70656772/7390856

Answer (score 10):

If you are using SpringMVC for REST api development you can use

```
@RequestParam("PARAMETER_NAME");
```

In case of jersey you can use

```
@QueryParam("PARAMETER_NAME");
```

Method look like this

```
public String hello(@RequestParam("firstName")String firstName, @RequestParam("lastName")String lastName){

return "Hello " + firstname + " " + lastname
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

```
ClientResponse response = resource.queryParams(formData).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
```

where formData is

```
MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();


formData.add("Key","Value");
formData.add("Key","Value");
...
...
...
formData.add("Key","Value");
```

Comment: This looked promising for me, but ClientResponse does not seem to be available in Android...