# Restful webservice Query param issue

Tags: java, rest

We are using Restful web services in our project. I am passing object of below class to my webservice as Query parameter.

```
public class QueryDTO {
    private String name;
    private Object[] args;
    private Object[] results;
//with setters and getters
}
```

Here is my webservice configuration

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/")
QueryDTO executeQuery(@QueryParam("") QueryDTO queryDTO) throws Exception;
```

Here args may contain any of datatypes(String,Interger,Date ..etc )
When I call

```
rest/query?name="getCreativeExtractorPatternByName"&args={"473"}
```

I am getting below exception.

```
Parameter Class java.lang.Object has no constructor with single String parameter, static valueOf(String) or fromString(String) methods
```

Please help me in resolving this..

Comment: i dont think you can give an array in the query parameters, thats why exception comes up !  and also you dont need to put the values in double quotes for query params

Comment: see this for array : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484209/pass-array-as-a-parameter-in-restful-webservice?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Add a single argument construtor:

```
public QueryDTO(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

For injecting the parameters into your DTO object, it should consist a constructor accepting a String parameter.

You should provide a valid Query Parameter for successful injection in your DTO object.

Comment: Can you please explain me , why we need this? Meanwhile, i will try with it and let you know.